# React Native top Screen not covered

Tags: android, react-native, mobile-development

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LsiA.png)
as we see that the mobile has left some spacing in the top. how can I make my app ocupy full screen. I was trying to build this app in react-native-cli

I was expecting to cover the whole screen

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check this on your phone (real device). you wont see any space there . This happen on some pixels simulator.